# What is greatest integer that $2017a+2018b$ ($a,b\in\Bbb{N}$) can't make?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I try to solve question that "What is greatest integer that $2017a+2018b$ ($a,b$ are natural numbers) can't make?" I use Diophantos equation to solve this problem but I can't solve it. So I post this to get idea.

$2017a+2018b =n$ ($a,b,n\in\Bbb{N}$)
$2017(-n)+2018n =n$
$2017(-2018t)+2018(2017t) =n$ ($t\in\Bbb{Z}$)

So,$2017(-n-2018t+2018(n+2017t)=n$.
Thus,$(a,b)=(-n-2018t,n+2017t)$
From the up eqation we get 
$-n/2017 < t <-n/2018$.

Consider $l$ is length of $(-n/2017,-n/2018)$
If $l$ is bigger than 1, integer $t$ is always exists.
So, $l$ should be same or smaller than $1$.
$l=n/2017 -n/2018 =<1$
$n =< 2017×2018$
We can see there is no integer $t$ is exist where $n=2017×2018$.
Thus answer is $2017×2018$

Comment: This is not true: $2017\cdot 2018+2018\cdot 0=2017\cdot 2018$ is a solution. We have $\mathbb{N}=\{0,1,\cdots \}$. This makes sense with coins. You may use zero coins of a certain type.

Comment: I agree with you according with two things: 1) $0$ is not a natural integer; 2) the searched integer is greater than $ab-a-b$ . However it has not been proven that $ab$ is the largest number sought.

Comment: If we can or can not make $M = 2017a + 2018b$ with $a, b \ge \alpha$ then we can or can not make $M+2017 + 2018 = 2017(a+1) + 2018(b+1) = 2017c + 2018d$ with $c,d \ge \alpha + 1$.  So whatever the solution is with the stipulation that $a,b \ge 0$, the solution with the stipulation $a,b >0$ will but $2017 + 2018$ more.  So its the well know coin problem if $0$ is acceptable the max impossible is $2017*2018 - 20017+2018$.  So if $0$ is not acceptable the max impossible is $2017*2018$.

Comment: So user381793 is the correct solution if $a,b \ge 1$.  But if $a,b \ge 0$ then correct solution is $2017*2018 - 2017 - 2018$.

Answer (score 4):

*Theorem*: Let $a, b, x, y$ be non-negative integers such that $a$ and $b$ have no common divisor greater than $1$. Then the largest number not expressible in the form $ax + by$ is $ab - a - b$.

Proof: see [Art of Problem Solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h369312_find_largest_number_not_representable_by_axby).

*Corollary*: For $a=2017$ and $b=2018$ and $x,y$ satisfying this assumption, the largest number is $4066271$.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde: Undoubtedly very interesting question. I am somewhat confused however: please tell me if this means that $ax + by = ab-a-b + z$ always has a solution in positive integers for all positive integer $z$. If yes, then it would be easy to find counterexamples; if not, then $ab-a-b$ would not be the most sought positive integer. In what I am wrong, please?

Comment: Why would it be easy to find counterexamples? Don't forget that we require $gcd(a,b)=1$.

Comment: I post my solution. I'll be thank if you check what is wrong in my answer

Comment: @Dietrich Burde: $3\cdot5-3-5=7$ and $3x+5y=9\gt7$ has no integer positive solutions. I do not rule out being wrong in any way, but what would be my mistake?

Comment: @Piquito I think in the question it says "natural number", so $y=0$ gives a solution: $3x+5\cdot 0=9$. This makes sense with coins, too. So for me it is not a counterexample.

Comment: Precisely, reading user381793's answer I thought the same and it was the starting point of my doubt.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde: Absolutely, I saw this but $0$ is not a positive integer( many authors does not consider $0$ as a natural integer; don't forget that the invention of the zero was a great invention of Humanity).

Comment: There you are absolutely right.

Comment: natural = Non-negative $(\ge 0)$ is not the same as natural = positive $(> 0)$.  The same reasoning that tells you $ab-a-b$ is the largest impossible non negative expression will tell you that $ab$ is the largest positive expression. I think we can make arbitrary restirictions such as $ab + a + b$ is the largest impossible one where $x, y$ are both at least $2$ (why at least 2?  Why not?) or  $ab - 2a - 2b$ is the largest impossible for $x,y$ both at least -1.  (I'm not too sure about that.  Oh, wait, of course I am... wait, no I'm not.)

Comment: $M$ can or can not be made with $x,y\ge 0$ then $M + ka + kb$ can or can not be with $x,y\ge k$.  So although with the "coin problem" having $0$ of a coin seems perfectly acceptable (but not negative), as a purely abstract theory problem requiring $x,y > 0$ would have a solution precisely $2017 + 2018$ higher.  If $a,b$ is allowed to be $0$ the highest impossible is $2017*2018 - 2017 - 2018$.  But if $a,b > 0$ then the solutions would be $2017*2018$.  Same reasoning.

Comment: @fleablood: "I'm not too sure about that. Oh, wait, of course I am... wait, no I'm not." I liked this very much indeed. Regards.

Comment: I'm sure of it now.  $M$ can be made with $a,b \ge 0$ if and only if $M + xk + yk$ can be made with $a,b \ge k$.

Answer (score 0):

Euclid's lemma says that any $M$ can be express as $2017m + 2018n = M$ where $m$ and $n$ are integers, possibly negative.

$2017(2018k) + 2018(-2017k)=0$.

So if $M = 2017m + 2018n $ then $M=2017(m + 2018k) + 2018(n- 2017k)$ for all integers $k$.

So if $M$ can *not* be expressed as $2017a + 2018b$, $a,b$ natural, then $(m + 2018k)$ and $(n- 2017k)$ can not both be positive for any integer $k$.

Let's pin the wriggling eel down.

Let $m \equiv [m] \mod 2018$ so we can, without loss of generality, assume $0 < m \le 2018$. (If it *isn't* there is an integer $k$ so that $m + 2018k$ will be.) And $n \le 0$.  To maximize, $M = 2017m + 2018n$ with $0 < m \le 2018$ and $m \le 0$, we simply maximize $m$ and $n$ and $m = 2018$ and $n =0$ and the maximum number is $M = 2018*2017$.

If we need further convincing:

$M = 2018*2017 = 2017*(2018) + 2018(0) = 2017*(2018 + 2018k) + 2018(-2017k)$.  If $2018 + 2018k > 0$ then $k > -1$ so $k \ge 0$ and $-2017k \le 0$. Thus $M$ can not be made.

However $M + 1 = 2017*(2018 - 1) + 2018(1)$ can be made.

Strong induction proof:  Assume $M + 1$ through $K$ can be made.

Then $K = 2017a + 2018b; a > 0; b> 0$ is possible.  So $K+1 = 2017(a-1) + 2018(b+1)$.  If $a > 1$ then $a-1 > 0; b+1 > 0$. If $a = 1$ then $K+1 = 2017(a - 1 + 2018) + 2018(b + 1 - 2017)$.

Remember $K > M = 2017* 2018$ so $K - 2017*2018 = 2017(1) + 2018b - 2017*2018 > 0$ so $b > \frac {2017 *2018 - 2017}{2018}=2017 - \frac{2017}{2018} > 2017 - 1$.  So $b+1 - 2017 > 0$, and $a-1 + 2018 = 2018 > 0$.

So $K+1$ is possible either as $2017(a-1) + 2018(b+1)$ or as $2017(a -1+2018) + 2018(b+1 - 2017)$ (or as both).

Thus all $N > M$ are possible.

=====

Note the famous [coin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem).  In the coin problem we are told $\gcd(x,y) = 1$, and asked to find the the largest possible value that can not be made by $xa + yb$ with coins of value $x$ and $y$.  As it is assumed we may have $0$ of a coin but we can't have negative or non-integers, $a,b \ge 0$ which differs from your problem in that you stipulate  $a,b >0$.

But the reasoning is the same.

$xa + yb =x(a \pm ky) + x(b \mp kx)$ so wolog we may assume $0 \le a < y$ and so to be impossible $b < 0$.  The maximum such value would be $a = (y-1)$ and $b = -1$ so $Max = x(y-1) + x(-1) = xy - x - y$.

With the stipulation $a, b \ge 1$ we may assume $0< a \le y$ and to be impossible $b \le 0$.  Then max would be $a = y$ and $b =0$ so $Max = xy$.